# Why does the builtins module contain no code?

Tags: python, python-internals

All functions in builtins.py look like this:

```
def print(...):
    '''docstring'''
    pass
```

What's the deal with that?

Comment: Where did you see that? It would be useful to provide a path or link to the appropriate file at Python's git repo.

Comment: @metatoaster I expect it's what they see when clicking on a builtin in intellij/pycharm, because the ide opens a python stub file (which basically just has definitions & signatures for the IDE to parse / recognise).